# DOM Javascript: creating an array just with elements that display something

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, browser

Say an HTML file is purposely arranged to display a simple vertical layout so that I see a vertical arrangement of elements when the browser renders it. So there are no elements right or left one to another.
Now, for layout purposes, there are various other elements like < div> (for example) that are not displayed because they just are useful for CSS or the structure.  That is, just elements like < p>, < img> and other text nodes have something displayed (spacing and color areas are not important).
I would like to ask here if it is possible (using javascript on the DOM) to have an array  populated wiht just the elements that display something when rendered.
For example, say I have

```
< div class="div1class">  
< div class="div2class">  
< p>
some text here  
< img src="img.jpg"/>  
some text here too
< /p>  
< /div>  
< div class="div3class"> <img src="img2.jpg"/> < /div>  
< /div>
```

The array would be in this case:

```
0 text node  
1 img  
2 text node  
3 img
```

How to do that?

Comment: So you want an array of text nodes and images? You have to traverse the DOM looking for those elements (check each node's `nodeType`).?

Comment: @bfavaretto I also want < h> elements for example.

Comment: dont underestimate power of divs etc. they can also have background images ;)

Comment: @Mauno V. Let's ignore those cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited my answer according to the first comment below this post.

**Javascript**

```
    var nodeTypes = [];

    function getContent(elm) {
        if (elm.nodeType != 1 && elm.nodeType != 3) return;
        // skip if it's not an element or text node
        if (elm.nodeType == 1) { // element
            var comp = window.getComputedStyle(elm,null);
            var disp = comp.getPropertyValue('display') != 'none';
            var hidden = comp.getPropertyValue('visibility') == 'hidden';
            if (!disp || hidden) return;
            // skip if it's hidden
            if (elm.childNodes.length) {
                for (var i = 0; i < elm.childNodes.length; i++)
                    getContent(elm.childNodes[i]);
                return;
            }
        }
        if (/^\s+$/.test(elm.nodeValue)) return;
        // skip if it's empty
        nodeTypes.push((elm.nodeType == 3 ? 'text node' : elm.nodeName).toLowerCase());
    }

</script>
```

**CSS**

```
<style type="text/css">
    a span {display:none;}
</style>
```

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <div class="div1class">
        <div class="div2class">
            <p>
                some text here
                <img src="img.jpg" />
                some text here too
            </p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <a href="#">Anchor example<span>hidden element</span></a>
        </div>
        <!-- some comment -->
        <div class="div3class"><img src="img2.jpg" /></div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        nodeTypes = [];
        getContent(document.getElementsByClassName('div1class')[0]);
        console.log(nodeTypes);
    </script>
</body>
```

**Output**

> `["text node", "img", "text node", "text node", "img"]`

You will need to take many possibilities into consideration, such as an element that might look empty in code but actually has a background image. Using jQuery this would be much more reliable.

Comment: I put the classes just to make clear that the divs have some role in layout through CSS rules. I am interested in elements that displays something on the screen like text or image. Instead, I want that useful elements but invisible get ignored and do not go in the array.

Comment: @P5music edited my answer. I don't think you should rely on pure JS but use a more efficient approach such as using jQuery.